# Why does the program gives wrong output?

Tags: c, function, integer, checksum

**Checksum** of a number is the sum of all its digits.
I wrote the following program to find the checksum of a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read(){
    int read;
    printf("number between 1000 and 100.000: ");
    scanf("%d", &read);
    return read;
}
int calcSum(int num){
    int a;
    if (num < 10)
       return num;
    a = calcSum (num / 10) + num % 10;
    if (a > 10)
        a += calcSum (a / 10) + a % 10;
    return a;
}
void output(int in, int num){
    printf("checksum vof %d = %d", in, num);
}
int main(){
    int num;
    num = read();
    output(num, calcSum(num));
    return 0;
}
```

It works with some numbers like 11, 12 but not with numbers like 706

Comment: What is your definition of a checksum? Which output for 706 or 99?

Comment: For example: The checksum of 12 is 3, 1+2. So the checksome of 99 should be 18(9+9)but the result of my program is 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a > 10`, you are performing the same operation multiple times. Just do:

```
int calcSum(int num) {
    int a;
    if (num < 10)
       return num;
    a = calcSum (num / 10) + num % 10;
    return a;
}
```